# Customize permissions required by a managed package

Tags: managed-package, permissions, standard-objects

I've a managed package which when installed, shows that it has Read/Create/Edit/Delete permissions on all the standard objects (Step 1. Approve Package API Access - Extended Object Permissions)

Is this something I can control when creating the package?

This package actually only requires permissions to Account and Contact objects!

Comment: That's pretty broad. Are you sure it isn't touching children objects as well? Have you asked the company for an explanation?

Comment: @MikeChale I believe he's the package author and wants his app to now scare away admins when installing by only asking for permissions it needs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The feature that allows restrictring API access from managed packages (known as package access control, or PAC) has been deprecated and is no longer available for new packages. Existing packages that have it enabled can disable it in the subscriber org via the same method as the old answer. If you need to disable this as a package publisher you'll need to reach out to Salesforce support and reference bug W-4164180. Support should be able to turn on the PAC UI in your publishing org temporarily while you disable it.

You should not enable this (and generally, can't) for new pacakges that are not already grandfathered in.

(The source of this new information was talking directly to the packaging dev and PM team, so I'm afraid I don't have good public links to share)

---

### Old, outdated answer follows for historical interest:

Under the Setup > Create > Packages > (your package) menu there is an "API Access" field: [image: API access]. Selecting the "Enable Restrictions" link brings you to another page where you can specify exactly what level of CRUD access your application needs for various objects:
[image: API Access Privileges].

Note that once API access is enabled some system objects, like tags, are inaccessible to your application. If you make heavy use of system SObjects this may not be something you can enable.

Comment: I know it's been four years, but is there a way to set API Access Privileges in 2017? Can't find the section in my managed package settings inside my developer org.

Comment: @Sergey I updated my answer after talking to the packaging dev team. Short answer is: you shouldn't do this in 2017. It's going away.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately i don't think you can change permissions for managed package.